# C# If a condition is met, use the result and run it through the same method

Tags: c#, json, properties, generic-list

I am polling APIs that return different types of JSON strings in the same formats that contain lists, within lists, within lists. Here is an example:

```
[
    {
        "name": "string",
        "production": true,
        "start_timestamp": "string",
        "end_timestamp": "string",
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "scale": 0,
        "floors": [
            {
                 "number": 0,
                 "display_name": "string",
                 "map_image_url": "string",
                 "inside_image_url": "string",
                 "zone_maps": [
                     {
                         "name": "string",
                         "display_name": "string",
                         "zone_image_url": "string",
                         "zones": [
                             {
                                 "name": "string",
                                 "display_name": "string",
                                 "color": "string"
                             }
                         ]
                     }
                 ]
             }
         ]
     }
]
```

I am trying to create a dynamic method that I can us for all APIs that get the values of all the properties of the first list and concatenate them into a string for csv. Then if another list is found within these properties, go through the same method again until there are no more lists. Here is my current example code:

```
    public static string DelimetedString(object obj)
    {
        List<string> lineItem = new List<string>();

        Type myObject = obj.GetType();

        foreach (var v in myObject.GetProperties())
        {
            var objType = v.PropertyType.Name;
            if (objType.Contains("List"))
            {                  
                DelimetedString(v); //It is here where I would like to loop through the next list                                 
            }
            else
            {
                var value = v.GetValue(obj, null);
                if (value == null)
                {
                    lineItem.Add("");
                }
                else
                {
                    lineItem.Add(value.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        return string.Join(",", lineItem);
    }
```

The end goal is to have column headers that contain the property names, and the data for each property under this in a delimited format. Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: Sorry, I should have expanded on this. I do use Newtonsoft to deserialize into a json object.

```
MyClass _myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(responseJson);
```

I then send that object to the DelimetedString() function.

Comment: How did you get on with this, Mitchell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a problem like this you can do two things:

- Create a data model for the incoming json object, or
- use a object of type "dynamic"

I strongly recommend using Json.NET by Newtonsoft for deserializing json. 
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: Sorry, I should have expanded on that. I do serialize the json response, please see edit. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?:

```
public static string GetCsvFromJson(JToken node)
{
    var result = "";

    if (!node.HasValues)
        return node.ToString();

    foreach (var child in node.Children())
    {
        result += GetCsvFromJson(child) + ",";
    }

    return result.TrimEnd(',');
}
```

calling it:

```
string commaSeparatedValues = GetCsvFromJson(JToken.Parse(yourJsonString));
```

If you already serialized the json value, I will try to edit your function then. Instead of checking the type name if it contains list, it is not safe btw, you can go further until the object is value type or string (string is a reference type):

```
    public static string DelimetedString(object obj)
    {
        var result = "";

        if (obj.GetType().IsValueType || obj is string)
            return obj.ToString();

        if (obj is IEnumerable)
        {
            foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)obj)
            {
                result += DelimetedString(item) + ",";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
            {
                result += DelimetedString(prop.GetValue(obj)) + ",";
            }
        }

        return result.TrimEnd(',');
    }
```

Comment: This is a pretty cool way of doing it and would work very well for a simple json string. However it still have the same issue where if it comes across a list, it adds the list as the value.

Comment: @MitchellStone it bypasses the list values and goes into the inner nodes till it reaches the values. Have you tested it?

Comment: @MitchellStone please check my final answer.